# Express API routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my API, written in node, I have two middlewares:

```
app.use('/api', apiRouter);
app.use('/*', express.static('public'));
```

- the first one serves api (e.g. `/api/users` - returns all users, but do not enters my application)
- the second one server my application (written in React)

However, I tried to implement Server Side Rendering. To test if it even work, I just did simple:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send('<div>Hello SSR</div>');
});
```

However nothing is returned from SSR when entering my app. The same if I turn off JS in my browser.

I think that there's something wrong with `app.use('/*', express.static('public'));`

Looking forward for any help. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried with removing those `app.use` calls? And how do you _debug_ your application?

Comment: If you've added your `/` route after your `/*` route, it will never match.

Comment: @undefined I tried one minute ago. Surprisingly it doesnt work either.

Comment: How is defined your Router object? When you pointed that nothing is returned you mean 0-byte response or infinitely loading?

PS. Please note that the Expressjs documentation recommends a [reverse proxy](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#use-a-reverse-proxy) for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Routes are ordered. Add your `app.get('/', ...)` before your final `app.use('/*', ...)`.